# Can't Access the Application through the NodePort via browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-nodeport

I am trying to run a sample application via nodeport on browser on minikube which is installed using docker as driver, I have deployed the pods using following deployment.yml:

<<deployment.yml>>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python-app
  labels:
    app: sample-python-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-python-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-python-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: python-app
        image: SK/sample_image:firsttry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

I created service using below `service.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sample-python-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30007
```

then i tried running the app using curl cmd using node IP address and is successful as shown below:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2

$ curl -L http://192.168.49.2:30007/demo
```

but when i tried same thing via browser, it is not accessible giving error "site can't be reached" as shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiNKW.png)

Kindly suggest the way forward as i tried searching online for solution but i got confused as i am new to this.

Comment: IPv4 addresses `192.168.*.*` are [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) addresses and not exposed beyond the EC2 VM. You can `curl` the address from the VM but you will be unable to access it from other machines. I'm unfamiiar with minikube. You'll need to find a way to expose the Service beyond the VM.

Comment: people suggested using port forwarding and tried it but it's not working as i am confused in terminologies that which port to use where in following giving format : kubectl port-forward service {serviceName} -n {namespaceName} {portNumberToAccess}:{portNumberOfService}.